# Should captcha be used on every vulnerable page, or just on initial page load to deter robots?

Tags: hacking, captcha, domain-hacks

I do not know too much about how hackers compromise websites but am careful about sanitizing all posted data.

I am using Google ReCaptcha on most of the pages on a website. Would it suffice to have one ReCaptha at initial load to the site where all links are disabled until the ReCaptcha is satisfied or do I need to ReCaptcha on every vulnerable page?

Answer (score 1):

It depends whether your potentially vulnerable pages are indexable by search engines and accessible directly.

If they are and they don't redirect user to your initial Captcha check, Then the answer is yes, you would need to implement Captcha or redirect to your "initial" Captcha check on every potentially vulnerable page if user has not already passed the challenge.

But I urge you to consider UX aspect of it all. People are generally annoyed by captchas so my advice is to heed your own words and focus on properly sanitizing user input.

(Re)Captcha is not a magic solution. If someone wants to beat your captchas he will do so, either by buying captcha solving service or by other methods which have been covered ad nauseam on this network.

General rule of thumb is that best solutions are ones that users don't even notice, but which hinder the bots.

Focus on honeypots and similar solutions that don't interrupt user's workflow.

Example of honeypot would be a hidden input field which ask for some common input value, for example zip code or email, something that you don't actually require from your users, but which bots would automatically populate and you could do a check and reject cases where such fields are not empty.

Just keep in mind that any kind of Captcha is not replacement for proper validation/sanitizing/data type checks and other best practices. Also there are alternative solutions to consider, one example being humanpresence.net (Which I do not officially endorse, just mentioning it for the sake of completeness)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for this complete answer. I shall heed your advice.

Comment: If I were to save in session storage that a person has passed the captcha and check this on every vulnerable page before displaying it, would that be as good as forcing users to keep re-entering captchas?

Comment: Another wall of text incoming: Are you talking about client side e.g. HTML5 sessionStorage or server side session storage, e.g.PHP $_SESSION array?
I wanted to originally answer you within a comment just didn't have enough rep to post comments.
In both cases the answer is "yes, but..."  
It really depends how sensitive data on your site is and how important security is to your scenario so listing all possibilities even if I knew them all is virtually impossible. I would rather use server side session, but as I said depends on how sensitive the data is, and are you on shared hosting or not..